# Most efficient way to use tags in vim for Ruby on Rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, vim

I've been using vim for ~1 year and absolutely love it. I feel at peace when I use vim. However, there's been one thing that I simply haven't figured out how to use effectively: **tags**.

I've googled around, browsed SO, etc. but I still haven't figured out how to use them. When I tried, I ended up with a bunch of tags folders scattered throughout my project, but still was unable to use the tags in a productive manner. I mainly work with Ruby on Rails, but I also work on some WordPress sites as well.

Can someone show me the right way to set up tags in vim when working on Rails projects?

Comment: Not directly on point but Tim Pope has a bunch of ruby/rails oriented vim plugins on github: https://github.com/tpope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much Ruby-specific about tags; you probably want to use a single *tags database* in the root of each individual project.

What I was struggling with the most is the automatic tags update; I simply forgot to run `ctags -R` from the correct directory.

With the [easytags.vim - Automated tag file generation and syntax highlighting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) plugin, that's handled automatically.

Just put

```
:set tags=./tags;   " Search for tags upwards from the current file's directory.
:let g:easytags_dynamic_files = 1    " Also look for project-specific tags files.
```

in your `~/.vimrc` and create a tags file once in the project root:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ ctags -R .
```

Comment: Great answer! Hadn't found easytags.vim -- but it looks to be very helpful. SO ftw again!